# Problems with Enums in Unity C# for a Digital Card Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I've been trying to create two Scripts that would allow me to quickly and easily make various types of cards for my Digital card game. While most of the scripting works I'm having an issue when changing the colour of a card's background in accordance with the Card's type.

Here's the "Card Asset Script" which would allow me to state what type of card it is and how it works:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public enum CardType
{
    Weapon,
    Armour,
    Spell,
    Environment
}

public class CardAsset : ScriptableObject 
{
    // this object will hold the info about the most general card
    [Header("General info")]
    public CharacterAsset characterAsset;  // if this is null, it`s a neutral 
    card
    [TextArea(2,3)]
    public string Description;  // Description for spell or character
    public Sprite CardImage;
    public CardType Cardtype;

    [Header("Weapon Info")]
    public int Defence;
    public int Attack;
    public int Speed;
    public string WeaponScriptName;
    public int specialCreatureAmount;

    [Header("Spell Info")]
    public string SpellScriptName;
    public int specialSpellAmount;
}
```

Now here's the script for a One Card manager which edits all of the visual elements for each card to match those on the card asset:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OneCardManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public CardAsset cardAsset;
    public OneCardManager PreviewManager;
    private CardType Cardtype;
    [Header("Text Component References")]
    public Text NameText;
    public Text DescriptionText;
    public Text ArmourText;
    public Text AttackText;
    public Text SpeedText;
    [Header("GameObject References")]
    public GameObject DefenceIcon;
    public GameObject AttackIcon;
    public GameObject SpeedIcon;
    [Header("Image References")]
    public Image CardTopRibbonImage;
    public Image CardGraphicImage;
    public Image CardFaceBodyImage;
    public Image CardBackBodyImage;
    public Image CardBackDecoration;
    public Image CardFaceFrameImage;
    public Image CardFaceGlowImage;
    private bool Weapon_Choosen;
    private bool Armour_Choosen;
    private bool Spell_Choosen;
    private bool Environment_Choosen;

    public void ChooseCardType()
    {
        CardType Type;
        Type = CardType.Weapon;      
    }

    void Awake()
    {        
        if (cardAsset != null)
            ReadCardFromAsset();
    }

    private bool canBePlayedNow = false;
    public bool CanBePlayedNow
    {
        get
        {
            return canBePlayedNow;
        }

        set
        {
            canBePlayedNow = value;

            CardFaceGlowImage.enabled = value;
        }
    }


    CardType ChangeColour(CardType Type)
    {

        if (Type == CardType.Weapon)
        {
            Weapon_Choosen = true;
            Type = CardType.Weapon;
        }
        else if (Type == CardType.Armour)
        {
            Armour_Choosen = true;
            Type = CardType.Armour;
        }
        else if (Type == CardType.Spell)
        {
            Spell_Choosen = true;
            Type = CardType.Spell;
        }
        else if (Type == CardType.Environment)
        {
            Environment_Choosen = true;
            Type = CardType.Environment;
        }

        return Type;
    }


    public void ReadCardFromAsset()
    {
        if (Weapon_Choosen == true)
        {
            CardFaceBodyImage.color = Color.red;
            CardBackBodyImage.color = Color.red;
            Debug.Log("Applied Red to the card");
        }
        else if (Armour_Choosen == true)
        {
            CardFaceBodyImage.color = Color.blue;
            CardBackBodyImage.color = Color.blue;
            Debug.Log("Applied Blue to the card");
        }
        else if (Spell_Choosen == true)
        {
            CardFaceBodyImage.color = Color.green;
            CardBackBodyImage.color = Color.green;
            Debug.Log("Applied Green to the card");
        }
        else if (Environment_Choosen == true)
        {
            CardFaceBodyImage.color = Color.yellow;
            CardBackBodyImage.color = Color.yellow;
            Debug.Log("Applied Yellow to the card");
        }
        NameText.text = cardAsset.name;
        DescriptionText.text = cardAsset.Description;
        CardGraphicImage.sprite = cardAsset.CardImage;
        if ((Cardtype == CardType.Weapon) || (Cardtype == CardType.Armour))
        {
            AttackText.text = cardAsset.Attack.ToString();
            ArmourText.text = cardAsset.Defence.ToString();
            SpeedText.text = cardAsset.Speed.ToString();
        }
        if (PreviewManager != null)
        {
            PreviewManager.cardAsset = cardAsset;
            PreviewManager.ReadCardFromAsset();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Edit: Just a clarification about what problem is. What I want to happen is when a Type of card is defined in the Card Asset script, the one card manager could identify which is the card's type and then change its background's colour in accordance to the that type (Red for a Weapon card, Blue for an Armour Card, Green for a Spell card and Yellow for an Environment card).

However, what's happening is that even with a card type defined, the colour of the card's background doesn't change.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] as far as possible (I realize it won't be completely feasible), and take a bit more care with the formatting. At the moment, you say "the issue I'm having is with changing the colour of a card's background in accordance to the type of Card it is" but you don't explain what the issue *is*. What's happening at the moment compared with what you want to happen?

Comment: not entirely sure, as, like john skeet mentions, its not clear what the actual problem is, but i think it might be because in `ChangeColor(CardType)` you use `Type` instead of the class field `Cardtype`

Comment: What I want to have happen with the cards is for them to change colour based on the type of card they are (For example a weapon card would be red, A armour card would be blue, a spell card would be green and an environment card would be yellow.). However what is happening is that even if one type of card is selected in the Card asset script the card's background still comes out white in game.

Comment: it btw is the same in `ChooseCardtype()`. you initialize a local variable `Type`, set it, and then ... nothing :D

Comment: You haven't reduced the code in the question to just the relevant code, or formatted it. *Please* make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You're not invoking `ChangeColour()` from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I will start by recommending you to use a switch instead of several else if()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Besides that, I think there is an issue in the logic of your code. From awake, in case cardAsset != null you are invoking **ReadCardFromAsset()**.

Inside **ReadCardFromAsset()** you are already evaluating which of the four flag is active: Weapon_Choosen, Armour_Choosen... But as I see, those flags become true only in **ChangeColour()**, which is not invoked.